# Trying to write parsed JSON to file using Python Requests, but only saving 1 of 678 objects

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm retrieving data from the USGS, parsing it, pulling out the values I want, recomposing it into a smaller JSON object and writing that to a new file. Or, that's what I'm trying to do. I've gotten almost all of it working. When I run the script the resulting file only contains the data from the final object in the series. I'm very inexperienced with this stuff, so I apologize if this is obvious. I'm working in 'append' mode, so I was under the impression each object would be appended to the end of the file, but it seems like they are being overwritten. Insight is greatly appreciated.

Here is the script:

```
#libs
import requests
import json
import os

try:
    os.remove('newdata.json')
except OSError:
    pass

# daily values request url, generated from USGS web services
url = "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/dv/?format=json&indent=on&huc=17&startDT=2015-01-01&endDT=2015-06-04&parameterCd=00060&siteType=OC,OC-CO,ES,LK,ST,ST-CA,ST-DCH,ST-TS&siteStatus=active"

# create request
r = requests.get(url)

# parse
data = json.loads(r.text)

#jump forward a few layers in the tree
timeSeries = data['value']['timeSeries']

# counter for dealing with trailing commas
counter = 0

#extract relevant data for each streamgage site and write to file
with open('newdata.json', 'a+') as f:
    for site in timeSeries:
        json_data = '{'
        counter+=1
        json_data = json_data + '"sitecode": "{}"'.format(site['sourceInfo']['siteCode'][0]['value']) + ',' + \
        '"properties": { "usgs_name":  ' + '"' + site['sourceInfo']['siteName'] + '",' + \
        '"HUC": "{}"'.format(site['sourceInfo']['siteProperty'][1]['value']) + ',' + \
        '"lat": "{}"'.format(site['sourceInfo']['geoLocation']['geogLocation']['latitude']) + ',' + \
        '"long": "{}"'.format(site['sourceInfo']['geoLocation']['geogLocation']['longitude']) + \
        '}, "timeSeries": ['
        for chunk in site['values']:
            counter2 = 0
            for daily in chunk['value']:
                counter2+=1
                json_data = json_data + '{"streamflow": ' + '"' + daily['value'] + '",' + \
                '"dateTime": ' + '"' + daily['dateTime'] + '"'
                if counter2 < len(chunk['value']):
                    json_data = json_data + '},'
                else:
                    json_data = json_data +'}]'
        if counter < len(timeSeries):
            json_data = json_data + '},'
        else:
            json_data = json_data + '}'
    f.write(json_data)
```

Here is a gist with the [resulting file](https://gist.github.com/bwstud/63179bbf961ecddd10a2).

And here is a gist with the raw [json response](https://gist.github.com/bwstud/a1d474ed88e49ee61f4f). 
If, while you're here, you see anything else I'm doing that's obviously stupid, please let me know. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't build JSON from strings. Build a dictionary and use `json.dump(d, outfp)` to serialize `d` to the file `outfp`.

Comment: Building JSON from plain string would be highly error-prone and highly unreusable.

Comment: I'm sure you're both right, but I'm a little shaky on how to proceed. I've found some information in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) and in this [Dive Into Python 3](http://www.diveintopython3.net/serializing.html) book.

Would it be something like:
- get json response
- parse
- set each attribute in my desired structure to feature from the json response?

Something like:

   `>>> site['property'] = response['foo']['bar']?`

Comment: Your `f.write(json_data)` is outdented one too many levels. So it only gets executed for whatever `json_data` is after the last iteration over `site['values']`.

Comment: @LukasGraf answer is correct. Also, change 
`# create request
r = requests.get(url)

# parse
data = json.loads(r.text)` to `r = requests.get(url).json()`